# Save response data in variable using node https.req

Tags: node.js

i am working with some Third Party api that for some reason ask to send body with GET request, weird but i don't have control over that. Node-Fetch is not allowing sending body with GET request so i am using https lib. My issue is that i am trying to save the response as a variable but get undefined over and over again. If i console.log the results i can see the response and its all great but i need the data as a variable.

```
  var req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
   res.on("data", (chunk) => {
    finalResponse += chunk
   });
   res.on('end', () => {
    console.log(finalResponse); //Working
  })
 });
req.on("error", (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.write(postData);
req.end();

console.log('RESULTS: ' + finalResponse); //Undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's undefined because Node.js runs asynchronously, so the result is logged before it's actually finished.

In order to get the data, you'll need to wait for the request to finish from your consumer, which is accomplished by using promises, i.e. using `async/await`, and promisifying the request method, which means making it return a promise to the consumer, and resolve it when the request is finished.

Also, `response` is usually a `Buffer`, and if you need string, you can convert it.

Try this:

```
function getFinalResponse() {

    // return a Promise and resolve
    // when the request is done
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {

            const finalResponse = [];

            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                finalResponse.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log(finalResponse); //Working
                // if it's a string then you can use
                // Buffer.concat(finalResponse).toString();
                resolve(Buffer.concat(finalResponse));
            })
        });

        req.on("error", (e) => {
            console.error(e);
            reject(e);
        });

        req.write(postData);

        req.end();

    });

}

// consumer
async function run() {

    console.log('RESULTS: ', await getFinalResponse); //Undefined
}

// call the consumer
run();
```